# Are system calls directly send to the kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, posix, libc

I have a couple of assumptions, most likely some of them will be incorrect. Please correct me where they are wrong.

We could categorize the functions in a program written in C as follows:

- Functions that are sent to dynamically loaded libraries:

1. These are sent to the library that translates them in to multiple standard C-functions
2. The library passes them on to libc where they are translated into multiple system calls.
3. Libc passes those on to the kernel where they are executed and the returns are sent back to libc.
4. Libc will collect the returs, group them by c-function and use them to create 1 return for each c-function. These returns will be send back to the dynamically loaded library.
5. This library will collect all returns and use them to create 1 return that is send back to the original program.

- Functions that are either defined in the code or part of statically compiled libraries: Everything is the same as the category above but:

1. They program already does the translation into standard C functions where they are known or into functions calling dynamically loaded libraries in the other case.
2. The standard c functions are send to libc, the others to the dynamically loaded libraries (where they will be handled as above).
3. The creation of 1 final return based on the returns from both types of functions will be done by the program

- Functions that are standard C functions: They will just be sent to libc which will communicate with the kernel in the same way as above and 1 return will be sent to the program
- Functions that are system calls: They are NOT sent directly to the kernel but have to pass to libc although it doesn't do any extra work.

Security checks (permissions, writing to unallocated mem, ...) are always done by the kernel, although libc and libraries above might also check it first.

All POSIX-compliant systems follow these rules

Comment: There are two key distinctions: (1) whether or not there is a transition between user mode and kernel mode (the key definition, to my mind, of a system call) and (2) whether or not a called function is in a dynamically-linked (shared) or a statically-linked library.  Pretty much everything else follows from that.  Maybe also a distinction (3) whether a called function is "part of the program" or "somebody else's library".  Maybe also a distinction (4) whether there's a [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) involved.

Comment: *Functions that are system calls* That is a contradiction in terms.  A function is a function, and a system call is a system call.  Some functions map more closely to system calls than others do - and it's probably not as close as you think thanks to the change to `*at()` interfaces such as [`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html).  I'm not sure *why* there is this distinction being made in C between "functions" and "system calls".  If you're writing C, you're using functions. You pretty much need direct assembler to do an actual system call.

Comment: This is a quite good attempt to *classify* things... but it is a **bad question**. It variates from "unclear what you are asking" (there is no `?` in the post) to "too broad" (`Please correct me where they are wrong.` for many and many statements). You have a precise question in the title - make the question post to **elaborate that question**, not to introduce many other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be the same on Linux and on some other POSIX system (like FreeBSD).

On Linux, the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) defines how a system call is done. Read about [Linux kernel interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_interfaces). The system calls are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (but see also `/usr/include/asm*/unistd.h` ...). Read also [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html). The [assembler HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) explains more details, but for 32 bits i686 only.

Most Linux libc are free software, you can study their source code. IMHO the source code of [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) is very readable.

To simplify a tiny bit, most system calls (e.g. [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)) are small C functions in the `libc` which:

1. call the kernel using `SYSENTER` machine instruction (and take care of passing the system call number and its arguments with the kernel convention, which is not the usual C ABI). What the kernel considers as a system call is *only* that machine instruction (and *conventions* about it).
2. handle the failure case, by passing it to [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and returning `-1`.
   <sup>(IIRC, on failure, the carry -or perhaps the overflow- flag bit is set when the kernel returns from `SYSENTER`; but I could be wrong in the details)</sup>
3. handle the success case, by returning a result.

You could invoke system calls without `libc`, with some assembler code. This is unusual, but has been done (e.g. in [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/about.html) or in [Bones](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/bones/)).

So the `libc` code for `write` is doing some tiny extra work (passing arguments, handling failure & `errno` and success cases).

Some few system calls (probably `getpid` & `clock_gettime`) avoid the overhead of the `SYSENTER` machine instruction (and user-mode -> kernel-mode switch) thanks to [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't categorize things like that. When you program in C (but that makes no difference in almost all other languages), there is only **functions** and whatever is the real status of these, you call them exactly the same way. This is defined by ABI (how to pass parameters, get returned values, etc) and enforced by the compiler/linker. Of course some functions are just stubs. For example stubs to shared libraries functions (stubs may be need to load the library, dynamic link to the real function, etc) or system calls (this is more technical and differs from kernel to kernel). But from the viewpoint of your program everything is the same (this is why it is hard to understand difference between `fread` and `read` at the beginning: you call them the same way, they make almost the same job, what's the difference?).

POSIX doesn't say a single word about kernels... It just lists the C (and formerly ADA) API of a set of functions with minimal semantic (plus some command, tools, etc). Implementation of these is totally free.